# Pandas: how to get status of lines read when using read_csv?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am loading a very huge csv file, like 10 millions records, using `pandas` and `read_csv` method and I wanted to know if there is a way to show the progress of that loading, something like:

```
100,000 lines read
150,000 lines read
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show progress like this:

```
Completed 1 %
Completed 2 % 
... 
Completed 99 % 
Completed 100 %
```

you can try this:

```
import os, pandas
filename = "VeryLong.csv"
lines_number = sum(1 for line in open(filename))
lines_in_chunk = 500 # I don't know what size is better
counter = 0
completed = 0
reader = pandas.read_csv(filename, chunksize=lines_in_chunk)
for chunk in reader:
    # < ... reading the chunk somehow... >
    # showing progress:
    counter += lines_in_chunk
    new_completed = int(round(float(counter)/lines_number * 100))
    if (new_completed > completed): 
        completed = new_completed
        print "Completed", completed, "%"
```

Comment: How to print df with this option? Printing reader shows: <pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x7f7159ac9400>

Comment: @Tomasz I think this depends on the size of your file. You may process (print) each chunk, or you may do it in the end if you have enough memory to store entire content of the file. For the latter way, create an empty list before loop: `df_list = []`, then add chunks to it: `df_list.append(chunk)`. After loop: `complete_data = pandas.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)` and `print complete_data`

Comment: @Tomasz Keep in mind that printing entire DataFrame will result in only few first and last lines actually printed, with all the middle lines omitted, at least with native `print` command.